# Run for-each loop just one time

Tags: java

I have this following loop and  I want to run it for just one time.
how can I do that?

```
for (AnnotationData annotations : annotation)
```

Comment: use extra `count` variable and use `break`.

Comment: Why not just take the first `AnnotationData` out of your data structure you keep it in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just break out!

```
for (AnnotationData annotation : annotations) {
    // do something with "annotation"
    break; // only execute loop body once
}
```

Other answers are using counters or flags!? It never ceases to amaze me just how much code some people write to do the simplest of things. Typically, the more inferior the programmer, the more code they write.

#### Edited:

There is a misunderstanding by some commenters that a non-loop version would use "less code" or "less lines". Such claims are untrue... here is the precise non-loop equivalent code:

```
if (!annotations.isEmpty()) {
    AnnotationData annotation = annotations.get(0);
    // do something with "annotation"
}
```

This uses the *same* number of lines, but requires 23 *more* characters of code, although I grant you its intention is more emphatic.

Comment: Writing clear, concise code is a far more important talent than *lol i can write dijkstra on one line*. This code is confusing and antipattern. A loop should loop.

Comment: @lynks says you - this code is fine IMHO. I don't advocate, and eschew, code being terse to the point of illegibility. I'm talking about the great swaths of "code that does nothing" that beginners, or those who never learn, often write - like the code found in Nambari's or Abhi's answers.

Comment: those answers are terrible I agree. But do you not see that designing a for loop that by definition doesn't loop is terrible also? The only saving grace is that the compiler will unroll this anyway.

Comment: @lynks just for the record, it doesn't loop once. It loops once if there are any elements, otherwise it doesn't loop at all. There's more implied by this than you are crediting (the only ting missing is a null check). And what about the very common `while(true)` or `for (;;)` - are they "bad" too, because they have no terminating condition, they never exit, so are they just as bad? A loop that is infinite? This loop-once code pattern is a similar "abuse" of the loop syntax, but is also fine and crystal clear to me.

Comment: @Bohemian That's actually why I don't like it. If I came across this code, I wouldn't know I'd the zero-or-once behavior was intended or a bug waiting to happen. So I'd want the author to at least put in a comment, at which point why not just make it an `if` followed by getting the first element?

Comment: When we go that deep, I feel yshavit answer is far better than this. As yshavit explained, when we see this for syntax, people confuse whether it is bug (or) did intentionally, for which some comment is required. My example showed it with extra code instead of comments. Well that may be terrible, but that is one way we can accomplish this requirement. As lynks commented "inferior" has nothing to do with number of lines. In my view, Maintenance/readability has relation with number of lines. With current computing power, I am ok to have few extra lines as long as they don't leave bug.

Comment: @lynks OK, I can see how someone may wonder if it's a bug, so the `break` has had a comment added to address that and related clarity issues.

Comment: @Nambari OK, I can see how someone may wonder if it's a bug, so the `break` has had a comment added to address that and related clarity issues.

Comment: @Bohemian okay, but what's the advantage? You have three lines (including the closing brace). My solution, if you include the `if` check I suggest, would be... three lines, including the closing brace. So your answer isn't more concise, and is less idiomatic. I don't think your answer would end up on thedailywtf.com, but I do think mine is a bit more straightforward.

Answer (score 9):

A loop that runs once isn't much of a loop.

If `annotations` is an array, get the first one using `annotations[0]`. If it's a `List`, do `annotations.get(0)`. Otherwise, do `annotations.iterator().next()`. If you're not sure if the collection has at least one element, make sure to check that first.

This will be clearer, since when people see a `for` they usually expect a loop. One that actually, well, loops.

Comment: Best answer imo. I actually expected this as the answer - when I opened this question.

Comment: +1 No need for a loop at all if I understand the question as you do.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for any counter. Simply add a `break` in the end as:

```
     for (AnnotationData annotations : annotation){
        //your all code
        break;
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int i=0;
for (AnnotationData annotations : annotation){
 if(i==1)
   {
    break;
   }
 i++;
}
```